# remove a character from a data numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, nan

I am currently importing a .txt file to a `numpy` array.  The .txt file is organized by three columns with hundreds of thousands of rows.
Occasionally, for no apparent reason, the third column will have a `\` attached to the number.  This causes `genfromtxt` to import the number as `nan`.  I have tried using a replace function for `numpy`, but I believe this function is looking for a string because I get an "EOL while scanning string literal" error code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KhWA.jpg)

Any advice?

```
import numpy as np    
import numpy.core.defchararray as np_f

FLR = np.genfromtxt("C:\\Users\\brand\\Downloads\\Python\\MyFiles\\aupnipam_scan41_3DFLR.txt")
FLR = np_f(FLR, '\', '')
x = FLR[:,][:,0]
y = FLR[:,][:,1]
z = FLR[:,][:,2]
```

I've added a picture of what the raw data looks like to show what I mean by it having a "\" in the data

Following is the complete error code I get

```
File "<ipython-input-13-0876313d3bfc>", line 6
FLR = np_f(FLR, '\', '')
                        ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with numpy, you are missing a closing quote in this: `FLR = np_f(FLR, '\', '')` line.  You need to escape the \, so try `FLR = np_f(FLR, '\\', '')`

Comment: Can you provide an example of data where this occurring so that the error can be reproduced?

Comment: If you're working with one and only one text file, it may just be easier to 'find and replace' in a text editor, removing the '\' character. Not really a programming way to do it, but may be easier if it's just this one file.

Comment: @user3483203 I'm pretty sure that typo doesn't explain the issue described in the body of the question

Comment: His error is ""EOL while scanning string literal"", pretty sure it's exactly what his issue is

Comment: @Sagasaki there is always a programming solution :) it's not hard to replace characters in a text file.

Comment: @roganjosh Yes you're right - there is always a programming solution. I meant _my_ answer was not a programming solution, though there certainty is one. Just depends on the scope of the problem - using a sledgehammer for a nail, or a plastic toy?

Comment: @3483203 I guess we need a traceback to be definitive

Comment: @Sagasaki Yeah, I found the find and replace function on notepad, that did the trick.  Thanks

Comment: Please include the full error and traceback as an edit to your question.